# Automated type hints with Neovim

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim

I am looking for the option to display implicit type detections with Neovim similar to IDES like VSCode or IntelliJ display them. I am not sure if this is possible with a text editor since it is not technically part of the text (see attached screenshot).

[image]

A perfect solution would be a CoC plugin. I am mostly looking for such solutions for Typescript and Rust, but a general plugin would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a language server feature so any language server which supports this can be used but for rust-analyzer you can use [rust-tools](https://github.com/simrat39/rust-tools.nvim)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).